# rendering SDL_Texture with matrix

Tags: c++, c, opengl, matrix, sdl

So I've been using SDL, and I've been trying to do openGL function calls to be able to transform the things that i'm drawing to the screen, and it doesn't seem to be working very well.

Here's what I have:

```
glPushMatrix();
glLoadMatrixf(transform.getMatrix());
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, &rect);
glPopMatrix();
```

The image draws fine, but no transformations are done on it. Is there a way to do this? I know SDL_RenderCopyEx is available, but I want to use a transform matrix if it's possible.

Comment: Don't try to mix'n'match SDL_Renderer stuff and regular OpenGL calls, you're not gonna have a good time.

Comment: do you know of some alternative that I could do? Or am I just going to have to make my own Texture class around opengl?